# ToolTip is not loading properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to use tooltip on click of the div "associatedRecordDetails". I tried to load by below code but its going to blank page. Can anyone suggest where I am wrong? on click of the div it will go to another page user.jsp by ajax and load the content.

```
$(function(){
       $('#associatedRecordDetails').click(function(){
                $('#associatedRecordDetails').popModal({
                        html : function(callback){                 
              var  associatedUrl="user.jsp"                                               $.ajax({url:associatedurl}).done(function(content){
         associatedurl="UserSubmittedTickets.jsp?userid=1";
                            });
                     },
              max_width_pop : 700
      });

   });
 });
```

Comment: 1: paste some code in jsFiddle.net, 2: paste link here, finaly : wait for answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass the `content` variable to the `calback` function inside the `done` function, like in the [examples of popModal](https://github.com/vadimsva/popModal#examples) (the second one is working with ajax).

You could try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#associatedRecordDetails').click(function() {
        $('#associatedRecordDetails').popModal({
            html: function(callback) {
                var associatedUrl = "user.jsp"
                $.ajax({
                    url: associatedurl
                }).done(function(content) {
                    callback(content);
                    associatedurl = "UserSubmittedTickets.jsp?userid=1";
                });
            },
            max_width_pop: 700
        });

    });
});
```

Hope this helps.